# getting values from responseEntity object

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I am not sure how to extract values from a response object,.

```java
ResponseEntity<String> response =
    testRestTemplate.getForEntity(ResourceUrl, String.class);
```

[image]

Please look at the screenshot

I need to do `assertEquals(clientId,"205");` I need to do for all the values. How to do this? What is the best way since there are like 200 values.

Thansk for your time and patience

Comment: getBody should return you string. Can't you convert that to JsonNode and then run assertions ?

Comment: Thanks Barak. Will check

Comment: Do you have corresponding Java pojo/bean class for response json?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to convert the response to POJO class which would have all properties that are in response.

From screenshot it is visible that it is an array. So maybe something like:

> ```
> ResponseEntity<YourPojo[]> response =
>     testRestTemplate.getForEntity(ResourceUrl, YourPojo[].class);
>
> YourPojo[] arr = response.getBody();
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:
(Object refers to your response body json list)

ResponseEntity> response = (ResponseEntity>) restTemplate.getForObject("", List.class);

Answer (score 1):

You can try using ObjectMapper in Spring Boot as under :

1. create ObjectMapper Bean in your configuration class :

   @Configuration
   class YourConfig {

   @Bean
     public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
         return new ObjectMapper();
     }
   }
2. Now use this ObjectMapper as :

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

```
ResponseEntity<String> response =
    testRestTemplate.getForEntity(ResourceUrl, String.class);

SomePojoObject somePojoObject = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), SomePojoObject.class);
```

Note : Create SomePojoObject class with all the fields you are expecting in your response body JSON string.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks Vijay, I didnt need a configuration class. the below code worked for me. ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate.getForEntity(ResourceUrl,
    String.class);
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  List <Map <String,String>> list = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), List.class);